# Piano action too stiff after tuning, what's happened?

Tags: tuning, action

My new second hand schimmel 112 upright had its first tune three weeks ago. We bought it 8 weeks ago, let it rest and acclimatise then had it tuned with a mini service. The piano is 25yo and its last tune before we got it was 3 yrs beforehand, but it wasn't that badly out of tune till it was moved, and is in good condition.

Although there were a few stiff keys here and there, and this was mentioned to the technician, now the whole action is a LOT stiffer, to the degree that even to play  a trill I have to really put some force into it, whereas before it would trill without sticking!?? I saw him oil all the pins, so it wasn't that, also I'm sure he went through with a screwdriver or other instrument and optimised the hammers etc...I left him to it, so don't know exactly.

Am I right in thinking he's over tightened it somehow? Surely it shouldn't be the case that the whole piano action is significantly stiffer after tuning? 
Thanks!

Comment: Too late now, but would have been best if you'd tested the action before he left.  Get him back and have him re-adjust the keyboard.

Comment: Hiya, I did mention to him at the time that it was a lot stiffer, but he fobbed me off and said it would be fine and get easier, from which I took get looser. But it hasn't. I've written him an email, so am just waiting his response.

Comment: " I saw him oil all the pins" - what????? Depending what *you* mean by "pins" the result would vary from "waste of time and money" to "oops, if you are lucky and the "pins" were part of the action, this guy just completely wrecked your piano and the only cure is a complete replacement action - and if they were the tuning pins, the only cure is a new *piano*, not a new action."

Answer (score 4):

The instrument’s action may need a treatment with a proper lubricant to resolve the problem.  A more experienced technician will know what to use: a liquid called Protek CLP (cleaner, lubricant, protectant). This magic substance can flush out the bad oil and leave the pin and bushing refreshed and lubricated, freeing the key action.